# How to refactor this into ES6?

Tags: javascript, loops, internationalization, ecmascript-6, eslint

So I have a for/in loop to transform an object into an array of objects to use in a React typeahead component:

```
const languageOptions = []
for (const language in i18n.store.data[i18n.language].translation.languages) {
  languageOptions.push({
    id: language,
    label: i18n.store.data[i18n.language].translation.languages[language],
  })
}
```

However, I get an eslint error: `Using 'ForInStatement' is not allowed (no-restricted-syntax)`

How am I expected to perform such transformations now?

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
const languageOptions =
  Object.entries(i18n.store.data[i18n.language].translation.languages)
    .map(([id, label]) => ({id, label}))
```

assuming you don't need enumerable properties farther up the prototype chain. If you do, turn off the ESLint rule. =)